# Composite primary key and ManyToOne hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm learning Hibernate and I'm trying to make the Mapping work. My entities are as follows

Department:

```
@Entity
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String hqLocation;
    // getters and setters omitted for brevity 
}
```

WorkerId:

```
@Embeddable
public class WorkerId implements Serializable {

    private Integer workerId;
    private Integer deptId;
    // getters and setters omitted for brevity 
}
```

Worker:

```
@Entity
public class Worker {

    @EmbeddedId
    private WorkerId id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    // How to make @ManyToOne mapping work?
    private Department department;
    // getters and setters omitted for brevity 
}
```

Question: How to make `@ManyToOne` on the field `private Department department;` work? Simply adding the annotation results `private Department department;` as `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use a "derived identity"; so you should make `Worker.department` like this:

```
@Entity
public class Worker {

    @EmbeddedId
    private WorkerId id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    @MapsId("deptId")
    @ManyToOne      // <<<< edit
    private Department department;
    // getters and setters omitted for brevity 
}
```

Derived identities are discussed (with examples) in the [JPA 2.2 spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) in section 2.4.1.

Comment: This is throwing an error `Could not determine type for: com.example.demo.entity.Department, at table: worker, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(department)]`

Comment: Ahh. I forgot to include the `@ManyToOne` annotation. Maybe that fixes your error? @Vyshak

Comment: I also had to add `@JoinColumn(name = "dept_id")` and it worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: also could u please tell me why we had to add `deptId` inside `@MapsId`?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I should've asked about your column names too. : ) The `@MapsId` indicates which field in `WorkerId` maps to a foreign key to the appropriate `Department`. Since you are, effectively, mapping two fields (`Worker.department` and `WorkerId.deptId`) to the same database column, this tells Hibernate that the `department` field takes precedence for writing to the database, making `deptId` read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Question really is, which entity should be the owner of the relationship? would you like to map bidirectional or single way?

Here is the bidirectional example

```
@OneToMany(
      fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
      mappedBy = "department",
      orphanRemoval = true,
      cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Worker> workers;


@JoinColumn(name = "department_id", nullable = false)
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Department.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Department department;
```

fetch types are optional and depend on the use case

Comment: I tried one directional mapping and it complained `Table [worker] contains physical column name [dept_id] referred to by multiple logical column names: [dept_id], [deptId]` so I added `@Column(name = "dept_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)` on `deptId` in `WorkerId` and I got another error `Repeated column in mapping for entit`.